# Cannot install node packages using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

While installing any node package using npm, I am getting the following error:

> C:\Users\460785>npm install express -g npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
>   "-g" npm ERR! node v6.2.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3 npm ERR! code
>   MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>
> npm ERR! Cannot find module 'github-url-from-git' npm ERR! npm ERR! If
>   you need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\460785\npm-debug.log

I have tried to reinstall node.js again and again, one with stable version and also the latest version. Still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: What command did you run? The error points to the module `github-url-from-git` not being found - but there's also reference to `express` module.

Comment: if i run any command..for example if i run "npm install mongoose  --save" I get the same error. So i cant install any package right now. For any package installation its throwing the same error.

Comment: Could you try running this command `npm -v` to see which version is running, or if `npm` is at least working properly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like multiple persons on [github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3540) had a similiar problem.

As the user GregWoods stated there you might want to uninstall node.js completly and delete all remaining files in your Program Files Folder and then install again.

Comment: After removing node, I found my nodejs folder still had a node_modules folder. I deleted that and also deleted %AppData% npm and npm-cache folders. Reinstalled node and it worked.